# $(document).ready don't loading in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, document-ready

I have a url that gives me various parameters I need. I've managed to get the results, but for some reason it doesn't show any results at all in IE and I'm not sure why. It works in every other browser, but just not IE. I've checked the console and there's no errors at all, I've also used jslint.com to check the js code and that's all fine too.

I've removed everything else in the file so it only has this.

This is what I'm using to get the results. I have a separate js file that contains this:

```
function call(url, parameters, callback) {
"use strict";
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: url,
data: parameters,
success: function(data) {
callback(data);
}
}
);
}

function loadJackpots() {
"use strict";
call("https://www.domain.com/passkey", { JL: 0 },
function(data) {
var divIdentifier, obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
$.each(obj.JL, function() {
divIdentifier = "";
switch (this.gameID) {
case 2:
divIdentifier = "#snap";
break;
case 5:
divIdentifier = "#dominos";
break;
case 1000:
divIdentifier = "#chess1";
break;
case 1001:
divIdentifier = "#chess2";
break;
case 1002:
divIdentifier = "#chess3";
break;
}

if (this.gameID >= 1000) {
switch (this.stakeID) {
case 4:
divIdentifier += "_50c";
break;
case 5:
divIdentifier += "_1d";
break;
case 7:
divIdentifier += "_2d";
break;
case 9:
divIdentifier += "_2d";
break;
}

if (this.gameID === 1000) {
switch (this.subID) {
case 0:
divIdentifier += "_1";
break;
case 1:
divIdentifier += "_2";
break;
case 2:
divIdentifier += "_3";
break;
}
}
$(divIdentifier).html("$" + this.jackpot);
});
}
);
}
```

I use this to actually load the values:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
loadJackpots();
});    

</script>
```

And to display the results I'm using this:

```
<div id="chess1">
<script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write('<div id="chess1_50c">');
</script>$1466.85</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write('<div id="chess1_1d">');
</script>$1641.11</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess1_2d">');
</script>$378.04</div>
</div>  


<div id="chess3">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess3_50c">');
</script>$303.86</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess3_1d">');
</script>$523.02</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess3_2d">');
</script>$1473.72</div>
</div>

</div>
<div style="float: left; margin: 194px 0 0 185px;">
<div id="chess2_1">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_50c_1">');
            </script>$195.26</div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_1d_1">');
</script>$154.37</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_2d_1">');
</script>$193.76</div>
</div>
<div id="chess2_2">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_50c_2">');
</script>$146.84</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_1d_2">');
</script>$119.58</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_2d_2">');
</script>$145.86</div>
</div>

<div id="chess2_3">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_50c_3">');
</script>$2.96</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_1d_3">');
</script>$19.25</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="chess2_2d_3">');
</script>$121.89</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div style="height: 80px;">
<div id="snap">
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="snap_jp">');
</script>$862.16</div>
</div>      

<div id="dominos">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div id="dominos_jp">');
</script>$2823.18</div>
</div>
```

I'd be really grateful for any help with this as I've tried everything to get it sorted, but no matter what I do it just won't work in IE

I tried using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('test');
}
</script>
```

to see if  it was loading okay, but it didn't bring up an alert box at all - even if I removed everything and only had the alert code

Comment: What are you doing with all those `document.write`'s and `<script>` tags? I don't even...

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised it works in *any* browser.

Comment: I've removed all of the document.write's but that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error: missing `)` at the end of closing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have deleted it when I pasted it in here, I checked and it was there

Answer (score 0):

### Check your browser document mode, you may need to use $(function(){ instead of $(document).ready, I have found that document mode 7 and 8 have this problem, your browser may be retorting to IE7 document mode but running in IE9 window. HIT F12 to findout.

REVISION

Try this, you may need to add a ignore on your Eval statement, IE may be putting a break on your script because of it.  Try adding to the top of your javascript this     /*jshint -W061 */ see sample.

```
/*jshint -W061 */
function call(url, parameters, callback) {
"use strict";
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: url,
data: parameters,
success: function(data) {
callback(data);
}
}
);
}

function loadJackpots() {
    "use strict";
call("https://www.domain.com/passkey", { JL: 0 },
function(data) {
var divIdentifier, obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
$.each(obj.JL, function() {
divIdentifier = "";
switch (this.gameID) {
case 2:
divIdentifier = "#snap";
break;
case 5:
divIdentifier = "#dominos";
break;
case 1000:
divIdentifier = "#chess1";
break;
case 1001:
divIdentifier = "#chess2";
break;
case 1002:
}
```

});
       });
    }

Comment: I changed the $(document).ready(function() { to $(function() { but it still doesn't work in IE. I'm using IE8 and when I checked the document mode it said 'Quicks'. I tried changing it to 7 and 8 but that was the same. I know from other people though that it doesn't work in IE9 either

Comment: I added that but it didn't work at all. It's not coming up with any errors either. I've checked the console and there's doesn't appear to be any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered what the problem was. It appears that because the feed is coming from another server/domain it won't work in IE. I saved the feed as an json file and saved it in the same root folder as the site and it worked perfectly.